# Firebase cloud functions: Can you call functions from dll?

Tags: .net, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I know Bridge.Net can be used in node js and call functions from a dll. Is this possible to do use this with cloud functions? Would my local dll be uploaded if it is in the same folder of my functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions server instances run nodejs in a Linux environment.  If you have code built for some other OS or runtime (such as Windows, or a .net assembly), it won't work.  The only code that you'll be able to run is either JavaScript or a native executable built for Linux x86.